# FragmentActivity interact with Fragment type GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

**Question**, How can FragmentActivity (call it A) interact with another Fragment (call it B), and B is dependent on Fragment (call it C), but C has not yet been told to make B.

**Assumption**, C has not had OnButtonClick() yet so B has not been transtioned to, but A has had OnButtonClick() so now A and B can communicate.

**Scenario**,
A is some view that has a button to randomly add, update, delete, modify, the google map that's in B.
 C is some view that has a button to transition to a google map view, and this view can reflect the dynamic updates from B.

**Flow for A**, OnButtonClick() in A *interact with* **B**.

**Flow for C**, OnButtonClick() in C, *transition to* **B**.

```
public class A extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    onButtonClick(/*interact with B*/);
 }
}

public class C extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    onButtonClick(/*transition to B*/);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment map = new B();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_of_C, layout_of_B);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }
}

public class B extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
 @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){
  ...some map stuff...
 }
}
```

[image: abstract view]

Comment: i've thought of using the following approaches: (1) interface callback to place interface on A and callback from B, (2) instantiate B with something like FragmentManager or new class in my MainActivity since GoogleMap will be a shared object on some classes in my application, (3) pass a bundle from B to A, (4) serializable interface and pass from B to A, (5) use AsyncTask to communicate from B to A, (6) i was looking up EventBus, but i'm honestly unsure this will lead to a working solution.

Comment: possible to create a Fragment D which has Fragment B? refactor the code such that A interact with D, C transit to B and B has the common functionality that A and C need.

Comment: @hjchin, to clarify,
A (View) interacts with D (SharedGoogleMap),
C (View) transitions to B (GoogleMapLoader),
B (GoogleMapLoader) implements D (SharedGoogleMap)?

Comment: @hjchin, so, B will update D, and A will get those updates? I'm leaning heavily towards using interface for this, my only concern is that google map might not be ready before A gets the updates...please share your thoughts. thank you.

Comment: is your B the same instance to be accessed by both A and C? If that is not the case, u will creates different instance of B, then D could contain B in its fragment. D is similar be to C, the difference is you don't do transit, u attach the fragment of B in the xml of D directly. I hope i understand your question and answer correctly.

Comment: B should be the same google map that is accessible by both A and C, so, yes, it is the same instance. Perhaps I could instantiate B somehow through interface D long before A or C begin their events, and then this way I can have B accessible?

Comment: could I store B in interface D? perhaps a set/collection of this unique google map object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by doing the following:

(1) implementing an interface MapIf, MapLoader is my fragment that contains the shared google map,

(2) instantiating my shared google map object at the top level activity,

(3) implementing the map interface at the top level activity,

(4) getter at the top level activity,

(5) implementing the MapIf on my fragment B,

*note: the key was casting my **context** in fragment B as the top level activity to access my object through getter.*

```
/*
 getMapLoaderSet: need a set with capacity 1, unique map
 getMapLoader: unique map to be accessed
 onMapLoaderSet: do some UI msg Toast on data
*/
interface MapIf<MapLoader>{
 Set<MapLoader> getMapLoaderSet(); 
 MapLoader getMapLoader();
 void onMapLoaderSet(Set<MapLoader> s);
}

public class MainActivity (Top Level) extends Activity{
 private MapLoader mMapLoader;
 private MapIf<MapLoader> mMapIf;
 @Override public void onCreate(...){
 /*unique set of 1; only 1 google map per application*/
 final int capacity = 1;
 this.mMapLoaderSet = new HashSet<>(capacity);
 mMapLoader = new MapLoader();
 mMapLoaderSet.add(mMapLoader);

 /*interface to share map accessibility*/
 mMapIf = new MapIf<MapLoader>() {
 @Override public Set<MapLoader> getMapLoaderSet() { return mMapLoaderSet; }
 @Override public MapLoader getMapLoader() { return mMapLoader; }
 @Override public void onMapLoaderSet(Set<MapLoader> s) { }
 };//mMapIf
 mMapIf.onMapLoaderSet(mMapLoaderSet);
}

public class SomeView (A) extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, MapIf<MapLoader> {
 private Set<MapLoader> mMapLoaderSet;
 private MapLoader mMapLoader;
 @Override for OnCreate(...)
  mMapLoaderSet = ((MainActivity)context).getmMapLoaderSet();
  mMapLoader = mMapLoaderSet.iterator().next();
 }
 @Override for OnClickListener
 @Override for MapIf<MapLoader>
 @Override public Set<MapLoader> getMapLoaderSet() {
  return ((MainActivity)this.getApplicationContext()).getmMapLoaderSet();
 }
 @Override public MapLoader getMapLoader() {
  return ((MainActivity)this.getApplicationContext()).getmMapLoader();
 }
 @Override public void onMapLoaderSet(Set<MapLoader> s) { }
 }

public class MapLoader (B) extends Fragment implements 
 OnMapReadyCallback, MapIf<MapLoader> {
 /* same class members as SomeView (A)*/
 @Override for OnCreate(...)
 @Override for OnMapReadyCallback
 @Override for MapIf<MapLoader>
 /* same override implementation as SomeView (A)*/
 /* use getContext() instead of getApplicationContext()*/
}
```